# Haskell Patterns not matched: (_:_) _

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, guard-clause

I'm writing a function that takes an input a list, creates sublists, and retrieves n elements that it outputs into a new list. I'm writing guards depending on the value of the inputs, but I keep getting the error "Patterns not matched: (*:*) _".

Anyone identifies the issue?

```haskell
nKsets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
nKsets [] _ = error "Empty list should not be given as input"
nKsets l  n
    | n <= 0 = []
    | n > 0 = ...
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘nKsets’: Patterns not matched: (_:_) _
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exhaustivity matcher doesn't know that all values of `n` are either greater than 0 or not greater than 0, so it assumes that your second definition is not exhaustive. Use `otherwise` instead of `n > 0` to guarantee that a guard succeeds.

```
nKsets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
nKsets [] _ = error "Empty list should not be given as input"
nKsets l  n
    | n <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = ...
```

You can also use a third definition instead of two guards on the second:

```
nKsets :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
nKsets [] _ = error "Empty list should not be given as input"
nKsets l n | n <= 0 = []
nKsets l n = ...
```